# Managing intents with a Service

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am writing a simple notification scheduler. An AlarmManager in sending PendingIntents to the Service when it's time to fire the Notification. What is the method that's called by the Service when it receives the Intent from the AlarmManager?

Comment: the same method that is called when it receives the Intent from  activity or other service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an `IntentService` for this, and this method will get called on the service:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```